# How to set up spark cluster with different types of slaves

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I'm fairly new to spark. Right now I'm trying to see if it's possible to set up spark cluster with different ec2 instance types of slaves. The reason I want to do so is I have different limit of different ec2 instance types on my aws account. It would be great if I can run spark jobs with all of my available ec2 instances. I've searched around (google, stackoverflow, etc...), but it seems people assume the ec2 types of the slave nodes are always the same (I get that the driver node can be different type though). Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: What cluster manager are you using with Spark?

Answer (score 0):

I would contact AWS and have my limits raised so that you do not have this problem.

The issue that you will face is that Hadoop will assume that all nodes have the same resources available. This primarily means memory. If you run a lot of jobs that require a lot of memory, you will see constant failures. Otherwise you will need to configure hadoop for smaller jobs that will fit on any node. This will then mean that larger jobs will never run.

If you can select instances that have the same memory, you will minimize issues.

Unless you are an expert in configuring Hadoop (or want to become one), I would not do this. Stay with the exact same instance type for each type of node.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I just found something (posted below) which seems promising. Also, from resource utilization point of view, it really doesn't make sense for spark not to support so-called 'heterogeneous' clusters since we can't assume people can always get the same type of machines. Ideally spark should be able to smartly figure out how many executors to run on each slave nodes according to its specs automatically. And this is definitely doable programatically.